# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' in speedmonitor for raspberry

Tags: python, compilation

Hello I have this issue with a code that I found in a site and when I tried to compile it but an error popped up I searched it for hours but I found nothing. Can anyone help ?

```
import re
import subprocess
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

response = subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/speedtest', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().decode('utf-8')

ping = re.search('Latency:\s+(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)
download = re.search('Download:\s+(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)
upload =  re.search('Upload:\s+(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)

ping = ping.group(1)
download = download.group(1)
upload = upload.group(1)

speed_data = [
    {
        "measurement" : "internet_speed",
        "tags" : {
            "host": "RaspberryPiMyLifeUp"
        },
        "fields" : {
            "download": float(download),
            "upload": float(upload),
            "ping": float(ping)
        }
    }
]
client = InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'speedmonitor', 'pimylifeup', 'internetspeed')

client.write_points(speed_data)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speedtest.py", line 12, in <module>
    ping = ping.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score 0):

> `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

`ping` is `NoneType` because `.search` returns `None` when the string is not found.

This was in the line:

`ping = re.search('Latency:\s+(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)`

If the string is found then it returns `True` so maybe try using an `if` statement:

```
ping = re.search('Latency:\s+(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)
if ping:
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: I've already done that but this error pops out now
 
"download": float(download), 
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 're.Match'

Comment: @Cheat3d Well maybe the website is old and the package `re` has changed, or they made a mistake. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html  The `.group` can result even in a tuple while `float()` takes strings and numbers.

Comment: @Cheat3d Sorry I couldn't help